# MongoDB query to search in embedded objects with an unknown depth

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents that contains some information, and an array of item.
An item contain some info and may contain an array of attributes or another array of item (or both, but at least one of them)

So I have something like this

```
document{
  ... some info about the document
  "items" : [
    {
       ...info about the item (id, ...)
       "item_id" : 1234,
       "attributs" : [
           {
              "attribut_id" : 78954,
              ...informations about the attribute (id, value, ...)
           },
           {...}
        ],
        "items" : [
           { ... same structure as the items above}
        ]
     },
     {...another item}
  ]
}
```

I think you got the idea :)

Most of the time (like 98% of the time), I will get the document with a query on the info about the document.

But I might have to get a document that contains a specific item or attribute on the field item_id or attribut_id like

`"item_id" : 1234` or `"attribut_id" : 75464` at an unspecified level.

Is it possible to do such a query in MongoDB? Search for the field in a known structure, but nested to an unknown depth?

I didn't find a way, so I don't know if it is possible.

For now, i don't put items in an attribute, I added information about the parent to recreate the structure after I get the document.
So I can live without it, but I'm still curious and wanted to know if a solution existed.

So if anyone has an idea, I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: Yes it is, if not terribly efficient and you probably should not do so. But most importantly you have not said "what" field and value you are actually searching for. So this is very difficult to answer.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say it.
If i search for a specific item or attribute, it will be on the id field, something like
    find({"items" : {$elemMatch : {"item_id" : 1234}}})
for an item

Comment: Perhaps you missed the idea that you were actually being asked to edit your question. Trying to post additional details in comments is never a good idea. And it did not work for you BTW

Comment: sorry, i didn't get that. I edited it. I hope it makes things more clear now

Comment: Actually is does not. I would have been expecting you to clarify that you were actually looking for field `"name": "Fred"` or something like that at an unspecified level. That is something that can be answered, but you are not making that point clear in your question

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for according attention to my question. I'm not sure i understand what you mean, so i hope i made my point clearer with this edit.